# How to add css file in magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2

My  default_header_block.xml path is 
[image]

> app/design/frontend/custom-theme/my-first-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

my css file

> app/design/frontend/custom-theme/my-first-theme/web/css/abc.css

But my abc.css file loaded inside following structure
[image]

> pub/static/frontend/custom-theme/my-first-theme/en_US/css/abc.css

it will not display source path..
[image]

I followed the below steps to clear cache:

remove files inside 'var' folder and inside pub/static/frontend

How can I display my Custom css source link in website?

Comment: Did you ran the php bin/magento s:s:d and followed by php bin/magento c:f

Answer (score 7):

In order to do add custom css and load last, you must set up a custom theme.

- Create theme:
  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html
- Make sure that you set your Magento application to the developer
- mode. Add the following folders to your custom theme

> app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / Magento_Theme / layout
>   app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / web / css

Create the following files:

> app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme] / Magento_Theme / layout
>   / default_head_blocks.xml 
>   
> app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme]
>   / web / css / local-m.css app / design / frontend / [vendor] / [theme]
>   / web / css / local-l.css

place this code within default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/local-m.css" />
    <css src="css/local-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
  </head>
</page>
```

- Apply your theme:
  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html
- Deploy static resources (SSH to magento root):

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy